# MYSQL Counting matching results across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following tables

Business

```
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | b_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | b_name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Locations

```
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | l_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | l_name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | b_id        | big(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Jobs

```
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | j_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | j_name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | b_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | l_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

People

```
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | u_id        | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | salutation  | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | first_name  | varchar(25)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | last_name   | varchar(25)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

People's Jobs

```
    +-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | pj_id       | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | u_id        | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | j_id        | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | l_id        | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to produce a table that shows

```
    +----------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
    | b_id     | b_name                  | Locations  | Jobs       | People     |
    +----------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
    |       21 | Widgets Inc             |          0 |          x |          0 |
    |       24 | Prince Privates         |          0 |          0 |          0 |
    |       23 | Halon plc               |          x |          0 |          0 |
    |       18 | Stinky Hotels           |          x |          x |          x |
    |       20 | Pylon Catering Corps    |          x |          x |          x |
    |       22 | Skytrain Biscuits       |          0 |          0 |          0 |
    +----------+-------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I can achieve a correct count of matching locations for each business with:

```
SELECT b.b_id,
       b.b_name,
       count(l.l_id) AS locations
FROM business AS b
LEFT JOIN locations AS l ON b.b_id=l.b_id
GROUP BY b.b_id
ORDER BY b_name
```

If I extend it to include a count of the jobs at each business and then the count of people at each business it all goes pear shaped.

I know that the following is inherently wrong with regards to getting the count of people (as people can hold more than 1 job). I don't know if I need to use sub selects or COALESCE?

```
SELECT b.b_id,
       b.b_name,
       count(l.l_id) AS locations,
       count(j.j_id) AS jobs,
       count(p.u_id) AS people
FROM business AS b
LEFT JOIN locations AS l ON b.b_id=l.b_id
LEFT JOIN job AS j ON b.b_id=j.b_id
LEFT JOIN people_jobs AS p ON l.l_id=p.l_id
GROUP BY b.b_id
ORDER BY b_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do a quick-and-dirty fix of your query by using `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT b.b_id, b.b_name,
       count(distinct l.l_id) AS locations,
       count(distinct j.j_id) AS jobs,
       count(distinct p.u_id) AS people
FROM business b LEFT JOIN
     locations l
     ON b.b_id = l.b_id LEFT JOIN
     job j
     ON b.b_id = j.b_id LEFT JOIN
     people_jobs p
     ON l.l_id = p.l_id
GROUP BY b.b_id
ORDER BY b_name ;
```

It is also possible that the problem is simply that the `join` to `people_jobs` needs more conditions:

```
     people_jobs p
     ON l.l_id = p.l_id and j.j_id = p.j_id
```

And maybe a condition on `u`.

Your problem is that you are trying to do aggregation across multiple dimensions and getting a cartesian product for each business.  An alternative that is sometimes necessary is to do the counts in subqueries.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Adding distinct to the count() does seem to provide correct results. I am just checking this over now.

Comment: Yes, simply adding distinct to the counts does return correct results. Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This query should do what you need:

```
SELECT
  b.b_id,
  b.b_name,
  (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(l_id         ),0) FROM locations WHERE b_id=b.b_id) AS locations,
  (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(j_id         ),0) FROM jobs      WHERE b_id=b.b_id) AS jobs,
  (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT u_id),0)
     FROM jobs        j
     JOIN people_jobs pj ON pj.j_id=j.j_id
     WHERE j.b_id=b.b_id
  ) AS people
FROM business as b
ORDER BY b_name
```

You don't need the GROUP BY if you use subSELECTs, as the outer query will return 1 row per b_id, no more.

If instead you do JOIN the 4 tables at the main query level, like you were doing, you have two difficulties:

- number of rows increases (avoidable with GROUP BY)
- a simple COUNT does not work properly (avoidable with COUNT(DISTINCT
  ...))

*(as shown in Gordon's answer)*

Comment: Thank you Frazz, so would this be more efficient that what Gordon proposes?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. With subSELECTs you can only calculate 1 column per subSELECT. In this case the JOIN on jobs is executed twice within 2 distinct subselects. With Gordon's solution it is only joined once. But engines do cache and optimize, and indexes do have their importance. So I cannot really tell. You should try both on a significantly populated and indexed DB to understand and be sure of which is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you Frazz. At this moment I will accept Gordon's reply as it offers the path of least resistance. But, I do appreciate your reply.

Comment: His is a good answer. I posted mine not for the reputation, but because it is different. Efficiency depends a lot on the engine. I have used firebird for many years, and it was really good with subselects (i.e. it would not have executed that JOIN twice). But I am not sure about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try This Query:-

```
SELECT b.b_id,b.b_name,count(l.l_id) AS locations,count(j.j_id) AS jobs,count(p.u_id) AS people
FROM business as b LEFT JOIN locations as l ON b.b_id=l.b_id 
LEFT JOIN job as j ON b.b_id=j.b_id 
LEFT JOIN people_jobs as p ON l.l_id=p.l_id 
GROUP BY b.b_id, b.b_name  
ORDER BY b_name
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: The COUNT without DISTINCT will not produce the desired output on that JOIN.